# store json on blob storage using Azure function c#

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I want to store json on blob storage using azure function c#

For example my json is :

```
{
"a":"a",
"b":"b",
"c":[{"c1":"c1"},{"c2":"c2"}]
}
```

I would like to write to the file or even read from the file.

Are there any samples of writing and reading to files using Azure functions c#?

Thank You

Comment: There's good documentation on Microsoft for it such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `CloudStorageAccount` class:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.cloudstorageaccount?view=azure-dotnet

Using these you can create a `CloudBlobClient` and `CloudBlobContainer`. Then the `CloudBlockBlob` class:

https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob?view=azure-dotnet

Use the `CloudBlockBlob` class:

`CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromByteArray(...)` to Upload, and `cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToByteArray(...)` to Download your file.

Comment: Both links are broken mate

Comment: Is that a down vote because links to a third party site from over a year ago are no longer valid? A simple google of the 2 classes documented gives the current documentation.

Comment: Maybe next time just propose an edit with the revised URLS? They are only links to the official microsoft documentation that has clearly changed structure.